# No such slot QMainWindow when loading .ui file

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm doing some experimentation with Qt6 and Python using Qt Designer. So far I'm blocked trying to do an good old "onClick + hello world" example and based on my latest research this part of the development is referenced as "actions and slots".

So I've added a new **QPushButton** name **pushButton** and created a new **slot** for the QMainWindow (**MainWindow**) and called it *clickedNewConn*.

On the **Sinal/Slot Editor** add new configuration line following the **Sender -> Signal -> Receiver -> Slot**:

`pushButton -> clicked() -> MainWindow -> clickedNewConn()`

So far so good. Until I loaded my **main.py** and received the following error:

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such slot QMainWindow::clickedNewConn()
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

At a first glance I thought that would be the simple case of (somehow) loading the **.ui** file with a *custom* QMainWindow class that actually implements a function called **clickedNewConn**.

With that in mind I thought on passing a second param to **QUiLoader.load** function as mentioned [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html#PySide2.QtUiTools.PySide2.QtUiTools.QUiLoader.load)

```py
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def clickedNewConn(self):
        print("ops!")
# ...
ui_file = QFile("views/main.ui")
loader = QUiLoader()
window = loader.load(ui_file, parentWidget=MyMainWindow())
```

But I still got the same result. I also noticed that most of the tutorials with Python + Qt + .ui Files **never** mention or make use of this second param. Instead they are always talking about a python based version of the .ui file generated by a program called **uic**.

Does that mean the only way I can use custom slots is inheriting from the python class generated by the **uic**?

Comment: Based on your question, I suppose you're using PySide, **not** PyQt. PySide doesn't provide a direct way to "setup" existing widgets instances (which is what the loader tries to attempt), as opposed to PyQt's `loadUi`. The result is that, since `QUiLoader.load()` by default creates a new QWidget instance, the implementation of your subclass will be useless, since it will be used as a *parent*, not the actual widget itself. See [this possible solution](//stackoverflow.com/a/27610822) for a workaround (I never tested it, but it makes sense), otherwise just use PyQt if you're ok with its license.

Comment: @musicamante Sorry. Indeed I'm using PySide. I will checkout the link tomorrow morning. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @musicamante I've tried the link you suggested. I got the basic idea but it seems to need extra work to resolve few kinks. What actually work like a charm was your second suggestion to switch to PyQt. Thank you for the excellent answer.